# Is “cbsearch.site” a web robot, and if yes, how do I block it?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, htaccess, robots.txt

I saw invalid traffic in my Google AdSense account. I read some articles from the web, which all made it clear that invalid traffic could be caused by web "robots". So I tried to read on how to block these robots from my website. Some pointed out to look through "access logs" (which is very very long and frustrating), or use Google Analytics *(Acquisition > All Traffic > Source/Medium)* to identify unusual traffic.

In doing so, I found out that `cbsearch.site` is/was a referral to the site in the Google Analytics.

According to this [article](https://www.free-uninstall.org/how-to-remove-cbsearch-site):

> cbsearch.site – deceptive search site that infiltrates PC without user consent and affects Google Chrome, Safari, Mozilla Firefox or Internet Explorer.

My questions are:

1. Is *cbsearch* a robot?
2. If yes, will it be advisable to block and how do I block it in `.htaccess` or `robots.txt`?
3. If no, are there other ways to identify what is causing the invalid traffic or are there any common activities that do that?

Comment: "'access logs' (which is very very long and frustrating)" - You do _need_ to check your server's access logs to help you construct a rule that will block the request (if that is what you want to do) and to check that the request is actually hitting your server and is not simply [referral spam in GA](https://ahrefs.com/blog/referral-spam/).

Comment: You need to use StatCounter instead it had details about the visitors IP, where you can check later to see if it legit IP or just bots using host service, BTW refers dos not mean that bot is what visit your website if mean that visitors reach your website via cbsearch.site